# select value of array based on priority

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array that shows a available video quality like this:

```
$quality = [
    "720p",
    "480p",
    "hls-5999",
    "hls-666"
];
```

P.S: the output of available quality is different for each video and haven't regular order

I want to select available video quality by this priority

```
1 ==> 480p
2 ==> 720p
3 ==> SD
4 ==> hls-5\d{3} //regex
```

I tried this code, and i know it's definitely wrong , but i have no idea how to fix it

```
foreach ($quality as $key) {
    if($key == "480p") {
        $is_selected = "480p";
        break;
    }
    elseif ($key == "720p") {
        $is_selected = "720p";
        break;
    }
    elseif ($key == "SD") {
        $is_selected = "SD";
        break;
    }
    elseif (preg_match("~hls-5\d{3}~",$key,$matches)) {
        $is_selected = $matches[0];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the priority list to select from another list of actual video types?

Comment: When you say 'I know it's definitely wrong', what do you mean?  How do you know it's wrong?  What does the code do, compared to what you want it to do?

Comment: did you give up?

Answer (score 0):

Better ways to do it, but just search in the array in the order that you want.  You didn't state what you want to do if there are multiple `hls-5???`, but this takes the first one:

```
if(in_array("480p", $quality)) {
    $is_selected = "480p";
}
elseif(in_array("720p", $quality)) {
    $is_selected = "720p";
}
elseif(in_array("SD", $quality)) {
    $is_selected = "SD";
}
elseif($matches = preg_grep("~hls-5\d{3}~", $quality)) {
    $is_selected = reset($matches);
}
```